# Way to use different constructors on same variable based on switch-case outcome

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Consider this code:

```
switch(formatindex)
{
    case 0:
      var myExporter = new PngExporter { Background = OxyColors.Black };
      fileExtension = ".jpg";
    case 1:
      var myExporter = new SvgExporter();
      fileExtension = ".svg";
}
```

Of course this won't compile, since I declare `myExporter` twice. 
The question is, is there a neat way to choose the type/constructor based on the switch-case outcome.

In my case (which caused this question), the rest of the code using `myExporter`is the same no matter which type is chosen, because only properties that are used are width and height and these all behave the same way with both types of exporters.

I don't want to write the subsequent code twice, which is why I thought I could do something similar to the shown code.

Comment: Declare the variable before the `switch`: `var myExporter;`, then `myExporter =` within the cases.

Comment: Which type do you intend it to be?

Comment: `var Exporter` won't compile either without giving it a type I guess.

Comment: Oh, you probably need to use a common ancestor type instead of `var` then.

Comment: If the code using myExporter is the same, then I guess your PngExporter and your SvgExporter both implement the same interface. So just define 'IInterface myExporter' before your switch...

Comment: If they are descendants of the same type, you can build out a factory pattern.

Comment: @user202729 the user can choose the type, so I don't know beforehand

Comment: Take a look at the Factory Design Pattern - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Another option would be to define it as `dynamic`, but you're much better off if you can give it a concrete type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two types inherit from the same base class/interface then:

```
BaseTypeClass myExporter;
switch(formatindex)
{
    case 0:
      myExporter = new PngExporter { Background = OxyColors.Black };
      fileExtension = ".jpg";
    case 1:
      myExporter = new SvgExporter();
      fileExtension = ".svg";
}
```

If you can't add a common ancestor for the two then consider creating wrappers that do have.

---

In any case if these are the only two cases you have consider using an `if-else`:

```
BaseTypeClass myExporter;
if (formatindex == 0)
{
      myExporter = new PngExporter { Background = OxyColors.Black };
      fileExtension = ".jpg";
}
else
{
      myExporter = new SvgExporter();
      fileExtension = ".svg";
}
```

In general, this kind of function matches the design pattern of Factory so I'd recommend reading into it.

Comment: Thanks, will have to look it up, they are the both plot exporters from Oxyplot. But this would be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Concerning the If-else solution: In my case I actually have 3 cases, so if-else would still be acceptable. However, I was curious about a general solution for this.

Comment: @RolandDeschain - Glad to here this helps. Also have a look into the Factory design pattern